# Is it possible to dump/inspect the back stack?

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

For debugging purposes I'd like to be able to log the activities in the back stack, but I've not seen any API to do that nor can I see it mentioned while searching. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442713/view-the-tasks-activity-stack

Comment: I don't want to do it interactively using adb, I want to do it programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in onCreate of your MainActivity

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
            new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                public void onBackStackChanged() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount(); i++)
                        System.out.println(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName());
                }
            });
```

The name printed is defined when you call addToBackStack:

```
...    
FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
...
ft.addToBackStack(name);
...
```

You can see the output in logcat.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, i really stack with this question too. Unfortunatelly no. And let's think why?

Java get to our hands :

**1)**  [Annotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation) - way with DI.(Reflection way) like a [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)
**2)** Parent class for log in background.

```
public class MainActivity extends LogActivity //for ex
```

**3)** With `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` but you should check where you stay at the moment, what the thread you inspecting now and other routine work.

#### Referal links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350814/accessing-the-java-call-stack), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1043461/2956344) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14705641/2956344).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command
`adb shell dumpsys activity`
It will print a lot of stuff including the back stack at the beginning:

```
Running activities (most recent first):
  TaskRecord{45168b4 #2194 A=com.example.myapp U=0 StackId=22 sz=3}
    Run #2: ActivityRecord{a05a1af u0 com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.activity.MyActivity t2194}
    Run #1: ActivityRecord{5c017cd u0 com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.activity.MySecondActivity t2194}
    Run #0: ActivityRecord{6fe38b2 u0 com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.activity.MyThirdActivity t2194}
```

Another solution is to first type `adb shell` and press enter, followed with `dumpsys activity | grep -i run`. This will only show the back stack and no other stuff, but it takes two commands.